# Will an airtight container negatively affect yeast growth / dough expansion?

Tags: bread, storage-method, pizza, yeast, fermentation

I've had a lot of success making bread and pizza dough using the Jim Lahey "No knead" method, leaving the covered dough to ferment up to 18 hours.

I normally cover the mix tightly with plastic wrap, and it will bulge slightly, maybe up to 1cm at the centre with ~ 500g proved dough at the end of the time.

In the interests of saving waste, I have invested in a set of stainless steel bowls, which have relatively rigid lids with a double airtight seal. They are a push fit rather than clip over variety, so in theory if the CO2 production is excessive, they would pop off.

Will using these bowls have a detrimental effect on the quality of the dough if the lid stays on for the full duration? Or have I wasted my money here and could have just replaced the cling film with a large plate?

Comment: Not exactly an answer but a thought: Tupperware (at least in Germany) sells one of their bowls as “popping bowl” for yeast dough, with the sales pitch that the “pop” will alert you that the dough is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should not impact your rise at all, unless the container is too small to allow for dough expansion.  In which case, you might have a mess on your hands.  Many people (me included) use sealable containers, though I more frequently just use a clean kitchen towel (a plate would work too), the idea is just to keep the dough from drying.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @moscafj.

However, one consideration might be anaerobic respiration rather than aerobic - resulting in some alcohol being produced.

Over normal rising times I don't think this will reach any level that might either kill the yeast (around 10-12% usually) or produce intoxication of the consumer, but it might well produce a moderate amount of lactic acid, which could result in a slightly sour taste to the bread.